# passing EditText content by SharedPreference

Tags: java, android

In my application i have 2 activities , I want to type a URL address in EditText of SettingsActivity and use it in MainActivity but i can't ...

This is my SettingsActivity :

```
 public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

Switch aSwitch;
EditText editText;
String URL_ENDPOINT;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEnd);
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("edittext", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edt = sp.edit();
    String URLValue = editText.getText().toString();
    edt.putString("URL", URLValue);
    edt.commit();
    editText.setText(sp.getString("URL" , URLValue));
}
```

And this is my MainActivity :

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


String URL_Endpoint;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_monitoring);


    //get URL for endpoint from SettingsActivity
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("edittext", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String URL = sp.getString("URL", "");
    URL_Endpoint = URL;
```

Comment: Your EditText is empty when SettingsActivity is created, right?

Comment: `editText.getText().toString()` in `onCreate()` will always return empty string.

Comment: have you checked by printing the log in MainActivity for that URL string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, have a look at **Android's lifecycle**

[image]

Now, that said, `onCreate` method is just called once when the activity is created, as you can see in the picture.

For this reason, getting the text of the `editText` in the `onCreate` method will result in an empty text (if not pre-populated).

Since I think you want to create a settings activity which set up some stuffs for the `mainActivity`, you have two ways for achieving your goal:

1. You can add a "Save" `button`. I will reccomend this since the user might input something and change his mind, and this way clicking "back" will cancel the operation.
2. You can save the `editText` value at `onPause` of the `SettingsActivity`. This method will override the value every time the user exits the activity no matter what.

Note: remember to popolate the text of `settingsActivity` in the `onCreate/onResume`, or it always will be empty.

Also another point is that, always as you can see in the picture, once you come back from settings activity `onCreate` is not called again. So you have, in `onResume` method, to take the value from the `SharedPreference` and put it in your `MainActivity's` textview.

First, i reccomend you to study that `lifeCycle` because it's really a core information for programming Android.

Comment: thank you so much , it worked , but i have another question :

When i type the URL in EditText and press Back , the EditText change to empty , What should i do that my URL stay in TextView even when i press Back ?

Comment: @amirofff sorry but I didn't understand.. which edittext/textview you mean?

Comment: Sorry , my mistake , i wrote TextView instead of EditText in my previous comment ... i want to stay the content of my EditText even when i press Back

Comment: @amirofff read my answer, if you popolate the value in the onCreate, the value will be initialized every time you go in the settingsActivity. do it the same way you retrieve it for the mainActivity

Comment: No ,In my SettingActivity i put SharedPref in onPause() method , but when i press Back my EditText change to empty , i also want to save the content in EditText even when i back to MainActivity

Comment: @amirofff I still don't understand.. if you press back you fire "onPause()" method, onStop and onDestroy. Your editText is not empty, simply it doesn't exists anymore.. If you save your SP in SettingActivity's onPause and in your MainActivity's oncreate you retrieve the value from SP, this will work fine. If it doesn't you are doing wrong something else and without code it's impossible to help you. Try debugging the flow of the activity and see where the value is set to empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("edittext", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edt = sp.edit();
String URLValue = editText.getText().toString();
edt.putString("URL", URLValue);
edt.commit();
editText.setText(sp.getString("URL" , URLValue));
```

Put this code in your onPause() method